# Calculating Sum of an Object Using ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, fileinputstream

Needed some help with my logic again. Assuming the `Loan` class exists, I have a file containing `Loan` objects. I am reading the `Loan` objects from the file and calculating the total Loan amount. I gave one of the instances a variable name `ld` just to prove to myself that `getLoanAmount()` method works.

Now at the end in my while loop, I kept thinking on how to calculate the loan objects but turn them into integers.  I'm thinking that the `input.readObject()` method is returning an instance of the object, so it would only make sense to go about getting the integer value like this:

```
sum = sum + input.readObject().getLoanAmount();
```

But, I'm getting an error saying that it can't find the symbol `getLoanAmount()` and that's where I'm puzzled. I thought I nailed it. Can someone tell me why my logic is wrong. As usual I would really appreciate it. Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
public class RestoringObjects19_7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int sum = 0;
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(
              new FileOutputStream("Exercise19_7.dat"));
            Loan ld = new Loan(1000);
            System.out.println(ld.getLoanAmount()); //WORKS HERE

            output.writeObject(ld);
            output.writeObject(new Loan(2000));
            output.writeObject(new Loan(3000));
            output.writeObject(new Loan(4000));
            output.writeObject(new Loan(5000));

            output.close();
            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(
              new FileInputStream("Exercise19.7.dat"));
            while(true) {
                sum = sum + input.readObject().getLoanAmount(); //ERROR HERE??
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is homework, the consensus is you should add the `homework` tag.

Comment: Note this function cannot actually throw an IOException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it's homework, so I'll give you hints instead of a full blown answer:

- The method `input.readObject()` returns type is `Object`.
- `getLoanAmount()` is a method that is defined on objects of type `Loan`.

Hope this helps you figure out what might be wrong with your code.

Comment: Ok, just from your answer I'm thinking that it may be a casting issue along the realms of polymorphism I'm guessing. Will try that....Just tried to do something like sum = sum + (Loan)input.readObject().getLoanAmount(); it didn't work. I appreciate your help. I will look further into it. Thanks for at least getting me on the right road.

Comment: @Addy75 That cast is casting the result of getLoanAmount and readObject, so getLoanAmount is still being called on an instance of Object.

Comment: ok. so it looks like I need to get the object first, cast the object second and the use the get method on that to get the integer value. ok I'm going to try different ways to see how to accomplish this. Thank you - I'm on it!